# Stopping action if requirements are not met

Tags: javascript

I want to check the validation of two text boxs if either one is empty. It showed show an error as an innerHTML and if they are both filled in. It will then continue to action. Here is my code:

```
function go()
{
  var toCheck = document.getElementById('myAnchor');
  if (toCheck != '') {
     return true;
  }
  else 
  {
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
  }
}
```

this does set the innerHTML but still continues with the action. How can I stop it from continuing?

Thank you!

Comment: What element and event is that function bound to?

Comment: your code does not match your question. what is `myAnchor`? Is it the input box? or is it the place where you want to show to error?

Comment: `<form name="form" action="data.php">
<label style="float:left"><font face="Comic Sans MS">* username &nbsp</label></font>
<input type="text" name="name" size="40" style="float: left;">
<label id='myAnchor'  style="display: inline; padding-left: 20px;"></label>
<br/>   <br/>
<label style="float:left"><font face="Comic Sans MS">* password &nbsp</label></font>
<input type="text" name="pwd" size="40" style="float: left;">
<label id="myAnchor2"  style="display: inline; padding-left: 20px;"></label>
<br/>
 </p>
<input type="submit" value="LogIn" onClick="return go();">  </form>`

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
function go()
{
  var toCheck = document.getElementById('myAnchor');
  if (toCheck == '') {
     document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
    return false;
  }
  else 
  {
    return true;
  }
}
</script>`

Comment: The id should be on the input field, not the label.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the value of text box,

Change the code to

```
 function go()
{
  var toCheck = document.getElementById('myAnchor').value;
  if (toCheck != '') {
     return true;
  }
  else 
  {
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
  }
}
```

Comment: function go() { if (document.form.name.value == "") { document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML = "A"; return false; } else { return true; } } </script>


THIS WORKS !!!

Comment: You still got an innerHTML in there :)

Answer (score 0):

Textfields use the value attribute.

```
  document.getElementById('myAnchor').value = 'Fred Flinstone';
```

An empty textfield would have a value of "".

```
function go()
{
    var toCheck = document.getElementById('myAnchor');
    if (toCheck.value != "") {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        toCheck.value = 'Fred Flinstone';
    }
}
```

Here's a working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form name="form" action="data.php">
<label style="float:left">
<font face="Comic Sans MS">* username &nbsp
</label></font>
<input type="text" id='textfield' name="name" size="40" style="float: left;">

<label id='myAnchor' style="display: inline; padding-left: 20px;"></label> <br/> <br/>
<label style="float:left"><font face="Comic Sans MS">* password &nbsp</label></font>

<input type="text" name="pwd" size="40" style="float: left;">
<label id="myAnchor2" style="display: inline; padding-left: 20px;">
</label> <br/> </p> <input type="button" value="LogIn" onClick="return go();"> </form>

</body>
<script>

function go()
{

    var toCheck = document.getElementById('textfield');
    if (toCheck.value != "") {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        toCheck.value = 'Fred Flinstone';
    }
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: If I replace the innerHTML with alert it works. Otherwise no:(

Comment: Make sure the input tag has the myAnchor id, and not the label. Also, ids shouldn't use caps; css doesn't always like it.

Answer (score 0):

add the onsubmit on the form:

```
<form onsubmit="return true;">
...
</form>
```

if the return is false it will stop from submitting an opposite scenario if it's true. you could also call your functions on that attribute and do the same thing then if it doesn't fit the condition it will stop from submitting your form and do the other process you desire to happen.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you said that

> I want to check the validation of two text boxs

In that case you should be checking the value of textboxes, not the `myAnchor`.
I would change your html code like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40" style="float: left;">
<input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd" size="40" style="float: left;">
<input type="submit" value="LogIn" onSubmit="go();">
```

- adding id to the input boxes
- then change the `onClick` event to `onSubmit`. that way you can perform javascript validation in the function, then submit the form if all goes well, otherwise display the error.

Then your script will be like...

```
function go() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value,
      pwd = document.getElementById('pwd').value;

  if (name != '' && pwd != '') {
     document.forms["form"].submit();
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('myAnchor').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
  }
}
```